# $.each() on constructor? (Cannot call method 'each' of undefined)

Tags: jquery, constructor, undefined, each

Is it possible to use `$.each()` on a jQuery constructor?  If so, please explain the problem with this code segment:

```
$('<div/>').addClass(
    'forceSmallFont tableLayoutAutoOverride'
).applyHTMLclasses(
    paramaterObject.tableClasses
).each(
    paramaterObject.rows, 
    function(rowKey, rowValue)
        { ...
```

That is a single line in my code, and it's where chrome is reporting the error.

I've confirmed that `paramaterObject.rows` is defined.

`applyHTMLclasses()` is a custom function that more easily does `$.removeClass()` and `$.addClass()` if `paramaterObject.tableClasses` is defined.

**`$.fn.applyHTMLclasses`**

```
$.fn.applyHTMLclasses = function(paramaterObject) {
    if(typeof paramaterObject !== 'undefined'){
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).addClass(function(){
                return (typeof paramaterObject.classAdditions === 'undefined')?'':paramaterObject.classAdditions;
            }).removeClass(function(){
                return (typeof paramaterObject.classRemovals === 'undefined')?'':paramaterObject.classRemovals;
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is applyHTMLClasses? that's most likely what's causing the error due to improper chaining.

Comment: doesn't make much sense... the constructor's going to return a SINGLE new dom element. Why loop on something that'll only ever be "one"?

Comment: You're invoking the `.each()` method, not the `$.each()` static function. The method only takes one argument, the callback function: [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Seems like `applyHTMLclasses` is not returning `this`! You need to return the jQuery object if you want to do method chaining (also what Šime said). Also, FWIW, to remove and set classes, you could just set the attribute: `.attr('class', 'some classes here')`. No need for a custom function.

Comment: try adding .`end()` like `.end().each()...`

Comment: @Spokey: That wouldn't help since `.applyHTMLclasses` doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: Regarding your edit, looks like `paramaterObject.tableClasses` is `undefined` then. Why wouldn't you always return `this`?

Comment: @FelixKling ah, so if `paramaterObject.tableClasses` is `undefined`, return `this`; otherwise, keep it the same?

Comment: Always return `this`. Otherwise you cannot do method chaining. And I guess you would want that, no matter whether the argument is defined or not.

Comment: @FelixKling ah, ok.  now I'm getting `Object [object Array] has no method 'apply'`.  ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applyHTMLclasses` will presumably look something like this:

```
$.fn.applyHTMLclasses = function(classes) {
    this.each(function() {
        // do something
    });
}
```

It only needs a small change to allow chaining methods.

```
$.fn.applyHTMLclasses = function(classes) {
    this.each(function() {
        // do something
    });

    return this; // add this line
}
```

Comment: ty!  I've added that to my function, but now I get `Object [object Array] has no method 'apply' `.  i added the function in an edit

Comment: @Gracchus: That's because you are using `.each` wrong. The first argument has to be a function. `selection.each` and `$.each` are different. Since you are passing an array and a function, it looks like you actually want to use `$.each`, which cannot be chained (it wouldn't make sense anyways).

Comment: @FelixKling i'm basically `$.append()`ing with the `$.each`.  should i just make an `$.append()` and put the `$.each()` inside, `return`ing the iterated constructors?

Comment: is it intentional that you and @FelixKling have similar profile pics?  just curious.

Comment: @Gracchus: Stack Overflow changed all profile images to unicorns as an April Fools' day joke once. The image generator was created by a Stack Overflow user: https://unicornify.appspot.com/.